# How to add prefix for all elements and attributes using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to add the schema location and prefix 'ns1' to all the elements in the XML. The XSLT is working well to insert the schema location but is unable to assign prefixes to each element.
the sample input

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:StandardBusinessDocument xmlns:ns1="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader">
   <ns1:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>
      <HeaderVersion>1.0</HeaderVersion>
      <Sender>
         <ns1:Identifier Authority="EAN.UCC">1234567890</ns1:Identifier>
      </Sender>
      <Receiver>
         <ns1:Identifier Authority="EAN.UCC">BUILDLINK</ns1:Identifier>
      </Receiver>
      <DocumentIdentification>
         <ns1:Standard>EAN.UCC</ns1:Standard>
         <ns1:TypeVersion>2.4</ns1:TypeVersion>
         <ns1:InstanceIdentifier>0448431457</ns1:InstanceIdentifier>
         <ns1:Type>Invoice</ns1:Type>
         <ns1:CreationDateAndTime>2012-10-18</ns1:CreationDateAndTime>
      </DocumentIdentification>
   </ns1:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>**
```

To be

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:StandardBusinessDocument xmlns:ns1="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader" 
    xmlns:eanucc="urn:ean.ucc:2" 
    xmlns:pay="urn:ean.ucc:pay:2" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader ../Schemas/sbdh/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader.xsd urn:ean.ucc:2 ../Schemas/InvoiceProxy.xsd">
    <ns1:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>
        <ns1:HeaderVersion>1.0</ns1:HeaderVersion>
        <ns1:Sender>
            <ns1:Identifier Authority="EAN.UCC">1234567890</ns1:Identifier>
        </ns1:Sender>
        <ns1:Receiver>
            <ns1:Identifier Authority="EAN.UCC">BUILDLINK</ns1:Identifier>
        </ns1:Receiver>
        <ns1:DocumentIdentification>
            <ns1:Standard>EAN.UCC</ns1:Standard>
            <ns1:TypeVersion>2.4</ns1:TypeVersion>
            <ns1:InstanceIdentifier>0448431457</ns1:InstanceIdentifier>
            <ns1:Type>Invoice</ns1:Type>
            <ns1:CreationDateAndTime>2022-07-21T12:00:00.000+08:00</ns1:CreationDateAndTime>
        </ns1:DocumentIdentification>
    </ns1:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>**
```

XSLT -

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<ns1:StandardBusinessDocument xmlns:ns1="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader" 
    xmlns:eanucc="urn:ean.ucc:2" 
    xmlns:pay="urn:ean.ucc:pay:2" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader ../Schemas/sbdh/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader.xsd urn:ean.ucc:2 ../Schemas/InvoiceProxy.xsd">
<xsl:copy-of select="//ns1:StandardBusinessDocument"/>
</ns1:StandardBusinessDocument>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>**
```

Could you please guide me. Thanks

Comment: Write a template that transforms elements in no namespace to elements in the ns1 namespace, use the identity transformation as the base template.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're not "adding a prefix", you're changing the element name to be in a different namespace.

Second, `xsl:copy-of` copies elements unchanged (except that it has an option to drop unused namespaces). If you want to rename elements, then you need a full recursive-descent walk of the tree renaming each element as it is encountered.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="ns1:{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```